# does get method in multiprocessing queue remove the value from queue or not

Tags: python, multiprocessing

In python multiprocessing, while using queues for sharing data between processes, once the data has been *put()* to the queue, and when its retrieved in another process using *get()* , does this method remove the value from the queue or just deepcopy the value inside? e.g

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f(q):
    q.put([42, None, 'hello'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print q.get()    # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join()
```

In the code above, does q.get() remove [42, None, 'hello'] from the queue or not?

Comment: Yes, queue.get() removes the first item in the queue.

Comment: `multiprocessing.Queue` copies the API of `Queue.Queue`, as stated in the docs, so you could have just read the docs for `Queue.Queue.get`.